# Which test? Chi-square, non-parametric or Poisson Regression..? What species is the most frequently observed

Tags: chi-squared-test, nonparametric, poisson-regression, frequency, kruskal-wallis-test

I'm reposting my question based on previous comments received.
The problem:

10 x 100m sections of shoreline have been sampled to determine if one species is the most frequently observed species (dominant). Random point sampling was used within the 100m to make observations of the dominant species at those points. Dominant species was classified as either Species 1,2,3 or 4. In the data are lots of zeros, the sample size is uneven and the data is categorical. [image] Species 1 appears to be the dominant species, but how do I express this statistically? I've played around with all sorts of options in various iterations (transformed ANOVA & Kruskal-Wallis using mean proportions, chi-square goodness of fir and poisson regression - but I'm not sure these are the right way to go about it?) Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. Thanks
John

Comment: I think a suitable graphical display pretty much conveys all the important information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

don't make it complicated.  turn it into a test of proportions with species 1 as one category and species 2+3+4 as the other category. If you are just trying to show that species 1 is dominant, that will be sufficient.  If you don't need a test, then a confidence interval for proportions based on species 1 is better.